# How to link the correct directory for OpenCV on raspberry?

Tags: c++, opencv

I installed the openCV to my Raspberry following this [tutorial](https://qengineering.eu/install-opencv-4.2-on-raspberry-pi-4.html) but the files went to directory: usr/local/include/**opencv4/opencv2** instead of usr/local/include/**opencv2**

And now compilation fail even if I use #include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Comment: I would suggest you install again following this tutorial.
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/16/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi-4-and-raspbian-buster/

Comment: I see is following the same steps the think is that I need to use the C++ version, although the python is working fine the C++ code fails. Also the building process take more than one hour does it worth it?

Comment: what is the output of this command on terminal ```pkg-config --modversion opencv``` or opencv4

Comment: with opencv4 the output is: 4.2.0

Comment: You are compiling in the console, right? If so, do you link the code with the path of OpenCV? (this is for C++, because as you said it fails)

Comment: I have the error: openCV.cpp:1:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing. In the 'old' days OpenCV places its directories default in the /usr/local/inculde/opencv2 directory. However, with the major version changes since OpenCV 4, it gives a lot of potential conflicts when you had OpenCV 2 and 4 on the same machine. To overcome this problem OpenCV now places the headers default in the opencv4 folder.

You can now choose which version you want (if, of course, you have both installed): 
`#include /usr/local/include` which will direct to the 'old' version 2, or 
`#include /usr/local/include/opencv4` which directs to the version 4.

Most times, you don't include individual headers like opencv.hpp.
Please look at a snippet of code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
  VideoCapture cap(0);
  if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    cerr << "ERROR: Unable to open the camera" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  Mat frame;
  cout << "Start grabbing, press a key on Live window to terminate" << endl;
  while(1) {
    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.empty()) {
        cerr << "ERROR: Unable to grab from the camera" << endl;
        break;
    }
    imshow("Live",frame);
    int key = cv::waitKey(20);
    key = (key==255) ? -1 : key;
    if (key>=0) break;
  }
  cout << "Closing the camera" << endl;
  cap.release();
  destroyAllWindows();
  return 0;
}
```

During compilation you only have to give the location once.
This is a part of a Code::Block project file. The used mechanism is clear; just give your central location once. 
Beside, by linking the whole package, you don't have to link individual object files with there frustrating inter-dependencies.

```
    <Compiler>
        <Add option="-Wall" />
        <Add option="-fexceptions" />
        <Add directory="/usr/local/include/opencv4" />
    </Compiler>
    <Linker>
        <Add option="`pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4`" />
    </Linker>
```

I,ve placed some (deep learning) examples on how to use OpenCV 4 on a Raspberry Pi on [GitHub](https://github.com/Qengineering/OpenCV-Livecam-Raspberry-Pi). Here you see how to use C++ OpenCV.